# How do I bound Higher Rank Trait Bound lifetimes?

Tags: rust

I have an iterator trait which uses Generic Associated Types to allow the returned values to reference data owned by the iterator:

```
pub trait MyIterator {
    type T<'a>
    where
        Self: 'a;

    fn next<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Option<Self::T<'b>>;
}
```

An example implementation looks like this:

```
struct FooIterator<'counter> {
    data: Vec<String>,
    counter: &'counter AtomicU32,
    index: usize
}

impl<'counter> MyIterator for FooIterator<'counter> {
    type T<'d> = &'d str
    where
        Self: 'd;
    
    fn next<'e>(&'e mut self) -> Option<Self::T<'e>> {
        self.counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        self.index += 1;
        Some(&self.data[self.index])
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to have a factory that returns `impl MyIterator` objects without making the implementing types public. However, I can't figure out how to write the lifetimes.

My first attempt was:

```
struct Factory {
    data: Vec<String>,
    counter: AtomicU32,
}

impl Factory {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Factory {
            data: vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string(), "d".to_string()],
            counter: AtomicU32::new(0),
        }
    }
    
    fn create<'f>(&'f self) -> impl MyIterator<T<'_> = &'_ str> {
        FooIterator {
            data: self.data.clone(),
            counter: &self.counter,
            index: 0
        }
    }
}
```

However, that results in a double borrowing error when trying to use the returned iterator, as can be seen here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6490de8f21539537764d8f628454c5c1

Next I tried using a Higher Rank Trait Bound, which seems like it should work, but I can't get the following to compile, because it seems that `'g` is not in scope in the where clause (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=beb46184de6f96bf83b64e838da4a335):

```
fn create<'f>(&'f self) -> impl for<'g> MyIterator<T<'g> = &'g str> + 'f where 'f: 'g {
    FooIterator {
        data: self.data.clone(),
        counter: &self.counter,
        index: 0
    }
}
```

Without the return `impl MyIterator` the code works fine, but I don't want to expose the `FooIterator` type. See this playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c595c136077791a692ea6e0a41c057c

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies in the `MyIterator` definition, because there the `next` function takes a mutable borrow to self and returns something which lives as long as that mutable borrow, which is not what you would expect from an iterator.

This is subtle, because it does not make the code unsound, it just enforces excessive constraints, which in turn makes it impossible to use that trait without getting errors. A simple refactoring of lifetimes in the `MyIterator` trait made it work. [See the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6f04264c7421ebb9f75ee0bf87399453).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good suggestion. However, I don't think it works in my actual code because you removed the GAT. I edited my question to more clearly explain why I need the GAT. What I really want is for data owned by the iterator to be returned. Like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=823aca83a9618e6f548640534549761f

Comment: Then I think it's really your iterator design that has a flaw, because you expect to be able to provide a `Option<T<'b>>` out of a `&'a mut self`. Either you have `'a: 'b`, in which case it's just like if you got a mutable borrow (you won't be able to hold two immutable borrows at the same time), or it's not the case, but then you don't know whether  `T<'b>` will always be valid.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the limitations, but I'm actually ok with that. As you can see in the last playground example (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=614bcc9b8c890c68725b800bce0b604b), it works just fine without the impl Trait return type. My iterator design is also the same as the one from the Generic Associated Type RFC, so I think it's the right way to design it: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md#motivation

I'm just not sure how to make it work with return impl Trait

Comment: @cberner interesting, I fear I cannot answer your question then, besides the fact that the unbound `'g` in your code simply stems from the fact that the `where` is interpreted as if it was the additional bounds of the whole function, not specifically of the `for<'g> ...`, and the function signature knows nothing of `'g` (`'g`'s bound scope is only inside the `for<'g>`).